# Why do I have to enter my keyring password for a WiFi password?

Tags: wireless, password, gnome-keyring

My Ubuntu 14.04 asks me every morning to unlock my keyring in order to connect to a specific WiFi, namely [eduroam](https://www.eduroam.org/). Every other network works immediately. I can't really use the machine until I unlocked the keyring. Normally the keyring gets unlocked when signing in, but I sign in automatically.

Can I make Ubuntu simply connect to eduroam without asking for my permission or is there a problem wit the missing certificate authority?

I tried to I made sure that all users may connect to this network. This results in the following warning message:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Im not quite sure why exactly, but if you save eduroams password in order to connect automatically, it is saved in Default Keyring (unlike all other networks I use, but eduroam has WPA2 enterprise security, maybe thats why..)

You can solve your problem by setting Deafult keyring pwd to "". To do this, open application Passwords and Keys (found in that thing in top left corner of the screen), right click on "Default keyring" folder (tab "Passwords"), Change Password. Put your previous pwd, then continue and continue. Done, you will connect to eduroam without notice.

EDIT:

search for "Network secret for eduroam/802-1x/password" in any folder under Passwords tab, for exapmle in Login folder. It shoud be safe to change password of Login folder to empty string, as it is here:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/disable-unlock-login-keyring-ubuntu-13-04/

Notice the last line of the article: For auto-login, set pwd to none.

Comment: I don't have a `Default Keyring` tab. There's only `Passwords`, `Certificates`, `PGP Keys`, `Secure Shell`.

Comment: ...and in "Passwords" tab I have subtab/folder called "Default keyring" in which the password for eduroam is  stored (it contains namely "Network secret for eduroam/802-1x/password"). The "Default keyring" folder has its own encryption password I was asked to input when first connected to eduroam. So I changed it to empty string.  Maybe you have it in other folder of "Passwords."

Comment: Ah, the Network secret was under Login for my, but still `Passwords` folder. I give it a try and check tomorrow.

Comment: I have also a Login folder in Passwords, but it's empty.

Answer (score 2):

- From the network manager (wifi symbol in the top right).
- Click on edit connection.
- Select your wifi network (Eduroam in your case).
- Go to the general tab.
- Select "*All users may connect to this network*".

[image]

Comment: It's already like this, exactly as in your image.

Comment: odd, maybe try removing it and adding it again?

Comment: Not changing. But I receive a warning message, because I didn't choose a CA. See updated question.

Comment: It did not work for me. Any other solution?

Comment: @chandresh It might not work because of this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1158432 which causes the password prompt to show even if the password is saved.